# How to pull data from Salesforce using Java SDK in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: java, salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-communities

I am looking to pull the data from Salesforce using Java code in Eclipse IDE.
How do I install Salesforce Java plugin in Eclipse IDE? Where do I get basic example of pulling data from Salesforce using Java code?

Answer (score 0):

**Installation Steps**

- Launch Eclipse and click Help > Install New Software..
- Click Add....
- In the Add Repository dialog, set the Name to "Force.com IDE" and the Location to https://developer.salesforce.com/media/force-ide/eclipse45. For Spring ’16 (Force.com IDE v36.0) and earlier Force.com IDE versions, use http://media.developerforce.com/force-ide/eclipse42.
- Click OK.
- If you want to install an older version of the plug-in (for example, if you do not have Java 8), be sure to clear the option "Show only the latest versions of available software."
- Eclipse downloads the list of available plug-ins and displays them in the Available Software dialog.
- Check the box next to the Force.com IDE plug-in and click Next.
- In the Install Details dialog, click Next.
- In the Review Licenses dialog, accept the terms and click Finish.
- Eclipse downloads and installs the Force.com IDE and any required dependencies. When installation is complete, you will be prompted to restart. Click Yes.
- When Eclipse restarts, select Window > Open Perspective > Other, select Force.com and click OK.
- You are now ready to develop and customize Force.com applications in Eclipse!

**Note:**
 When you create a new project, you might be prompted about a new master password. This is a separate password of your choosing required by Eclipse secure storage, and is not associated with your Force.com IDE credentials. For details on Eclipse secure storage, see the Eclipse Workbench User Guide.

Comment: @KumareshBabu You can accept the answer if it resolves your issue, so others can see it as answered and accepted. Thanks!